# Return several number ranges in python

Tags: python, function, range

How can function return several ranges of numbers like:  `[1:input]`, the second one `[1:input-1]` etc. until `[1:1]`

Example:

**Input**:

```
5
```

**Output**:

```
12345

1234

123

12

1
```

Problem is that I'm new to python, so I don't know how to do it. I suppose that with `for` clause, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Try creating a string from `1` to `input` range of numbers and join them and convert it to int everytime in the loop.

Comment: Could you be more specific? A loop achieves exactly this.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? a bit of context will help

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop and count down from the given input to 1:

```
limit = int(input('Enter a number: '))

for i in range(limit + 1, 1, -1):
    print(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1, i)]))
```

Output:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

If you want to put this in a reusable function:

```
def print_sequence(input): 
    if type(input) == int and input > 0: 
        for i in range(input + 1, 1, -1):
            yield(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1, i)]))
    else: 
        return False 

print(list(print_sequence(5)))
```

Output:

```
['12345', '1234', '123', '12', '1']
```

Or if you don't want a generator:

```
def print_sequence(input): 
    if type(input) == int and input > 0: 
        rows = []
        for i in range(input + 1, 1, -1):
            rows.append(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1, i)]))
        return rows
    else: 
        return False 

print(print_sequence(5))
```

Output:

```
['12345', '1234', '123', '12', '1']
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. But if I put it into function how 'return' clause can return me all the lines? 

`def print_sequence(input):
if type(input) == int and input> 0:
for i in range(input):
return ''.join([str(i) for i in range(1, input - i + 1)])

else:
return False

print(print_sequence(5))`

Comment: @lisa I updated my answer. You can replace `return` with `yield` or you can build a list and add the strings there, then return that list outside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(length):
    return ''.join([str(i) for i in range(1, length+1)])

for num in reversed(range(1, 6)):
    print(fun(num))
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. Remember to format code properly.